# Javascript Knockout, finding property name from the value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two buttons, to sort which sort by player name and id. iam using two function for each of the sort like.

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'playerstmpl', foreach: players }"></ul>
<hr/>
<button data-bind="click: sortbyPlayer">Sort by Player</button>
<button data-bind="click: sortbyId">Sort by Id</button>
<script id="playerstmpl" type="text/html">
    <li> <span data-bind = "text: id"> </span>
        <input data-bind="value: FirstName" /> </li>
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function Player(id, name) {
        return {
            id: ko.observable(id),
            FirstName: ko.observable(name)
            };
    }

    var viewModel = {
        players: ko.observableArray([
        new Player(64, "Yuvi"),
        new Player(22, "Gayle"),
        new Player(91, "Adam"),
        new Player(19, "Flintoff"),
        new Player(56, "Malinga")])
    };

    viewModel.sortbyPlayer = function () {
        var unsorted = viewModel.players();

        viewModel.players(unsorted.sort(viewModel.sortFunction = function (a, b) {

        return a.FirstName().toLowerCase() < b.FirstName().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;

        }));
    };


    viewModel.sortbyId = function () {
        var unsortedId = viewModel.players();

        viewModel.players(unsortedId.sort(viewModel.sortFunction = function (a, b) {
            return a.id() < b.id() ? -1 : 1;
        }));
    };
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

Im trying to find the property which is being passed in the function, so that I can merge two functions into one..like

```
viewModel.sortbyPlayer = function () {
        var unsorted = viewModel.players();

        viewModel.players(unsorted.sort(viewModel.sortFunction = function (a, b) {

            if (Player[a] == "FirstName") {            // is string
                return a.FirstName().toLowerCase() < b.FirstName().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
            }
       else {
            return a.id() < b.id() ? -1 : 1;
        }

        }));
    };
```

Is there anyway to do sort in one function.. thanks

Comment: Your sort functions should return `0` when both input values are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave the two properties on the view model for `sortByPlayer` and `sortById` so that it's clear on your ViewModel what you're exposing. Next I'd create a function to wrap the sort logic but allow you to pass in an argument that indicates what kind of sort you want to perform (I've called this `sortFunction`). Then your `if` statement works as expected, and if you want to have other properties to sort on (if/when your `Player` object changes) you could even convert it to a `switch` statement:

```
function Player(id, name) {
    return {
        id: ko.observable(id),
        FirstName: ko.observable(name)
    };
}

var viewModel = {
    players: ko.observableArray([
            new Player(64, "Yuvi"),
            new Player(22, "Gayle"),
            new Player(91, "Adam"),
            new Player(19, "Flintoff"),
            new Player(56, "Malinga")
    ])
};

var sortFunction = function (sortBy) {
    return function () {
        var unsortedId = viewModel.players();
        viewModel.players(
            unsortedId.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (sortBy === 'player') {
                    return a.FirstName().toLowerCase() < b.FirstName().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    return a.id() < b.id() ? -1 : 1;
                }
            })
        );
    };
};

viewModel.sortbyPlayer = sortFunction('player');
viewModel.sortbyId = sortFunction('id');

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more universal sorting function ..
you can check for the property `type` .. not its `name`. This will work for your case and in more general cases:

```
viewModel.sortbyPlayer = function () {
    var unsorted = viewModel.players();

    viewModel.players(unsorted.sort(viewModel.sortFunction = function (a, b) {
        if (typeof Player[a] === 'string') {            // is string
            return a.FirstName().toLowerCase() < b.FirstName().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (typeofPlayer[a] === 'number') { 
            return a.id() < b.id() ? -1 : 1;
        }

    }));
};
```

You can also use the magic property `arguments` witch gives access to they array of paramethers used with the function:

```
function someFunctionWithRandomParams(){
    if(arguments[0]){ 
        console.log('argument 1 of type'+ typeof arguments[0] +' and value'+arguments[0])
    }
    if(arguments[1]){ 
        console.log('argument 2 of type'+ typeof arguments[1] +' and value'+arguments[1])
    }
}
```